# How to forward remote trap data to a local folder other than var/log/syslog?

Tags: logging, rsyslog, snmp

My ubuntu receives snmmptrap data from a remote server and it goes to var/log/syslog but I wanted to forward that traffic to a different folder inside /var/log using rsyslog.conf or is there a another better way to implement this?

I tried adding couple of statements on Rsyslog.conf but it wasnt working.